# Constructing almost disjoint families

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ be an almost disjoint family of subsets of $\omega$ and let $\Psi (\mathcal A)$ be the Mrówka space ([definition here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033214)).

Let $$\mathcal I (\mathcal A)=\{X\subseteq \omega : X\subseteq \bigcup \mathcal B \text { for some finite }\mathcal B\subseteq \mathcal A\}.$$

Say $X\subseteq \omega $ is a *partitioner* of $\mathcal A$ if $A\cap X=^*\varnothing $ or $A\subseteq ^* X$ for each $A\in\mathcal A$ (here $^*$ means the relation holds for all but finitely many points). Note that if $X$ is a partitioner of $\mathcal A$ then so is $\omega\setminus X$.

A partitioner $X$ is *trivial* if $X\in \mathcal I (\mathcal A)$ or $\omega\setminus X\in\mathcal I (\mathcal A)$

I think it is a nice (and easy to prove) result that the Stone-Cech remainder $\beta \Psi(\mathcal A)\setminus \Psi(\mathcal A)$ is connected iff $\mathcal A$ has no nontrivial partitioners. My question is: How can we construct almost disjoint families (of subsets of $\omega$) with no nontrivial partitioners?  Are there some basic methods for constructing almost disjoint families that you can share with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve seen only one construction. Let $T={}^{<\omega}2$ be the binary tree of height $\omega$. For each $f\in{}^\omega2$ let $B_f=\{f\upharpoonright n:n\in\omega\}$ be the branch determined by $f$, and let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_f:f\in{}^\omega2\}$; $\mathscr{B}$ is an AD family in $\wp(T)$, so it can be extended to a MAD family $\mathscr{A}$. Clearly $|\mathscr{A}\setminus\mathscr{B}|\le 2^\omega$; pick any $F\subseteq{}^\omega2$ such that $|F|=|\mathscr{A}\setminus\mathscr{B}|$, and let $\mathscr{A}\setminus\mathscr{B}=\{A_f:f\in F\}$.

Now let

$$\mathscr{A}'=\{B_f:f\in{}^\omega2\setminus F\}\cup\{B_f\cup A_f:f\in F\}\;;$$

clearly $\mathscr{A}'$ is a MAD family. Suppose that $X\subseteq{}^{<\omega}2$ is a non-trivial partitioner of $\mathscr{A}'$. Note that $\{A\cap X:A\in\mathscr{A}'\}$ is a MAD family in $\wp(X)$, so it must be uncountable; since $X$ is a partitioner, this means that $F_X=\{f\in{}^\omega2:B_f\subseteq^*X\}$ must be uncountable as well. But

$$F_X=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\{f\in{}^\omega2:\forall m\ge n(f\upharpoonright m\in X)\}\;,$$

and the sets $\{f\in{}^\omega2:\forall m\ge n(f\upharpoonright m\in X)\}$ are easily seen to be closed in ${}^\omega2$ when the latter is viewed as the product of $\omega$ discrete $2$-point spaces, so $F_X$ is an uncountable $F_\sigma$ in ${}^\omega2$ and must therefore have cardinality $2^\omega$.

Now let $\{X_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}$ be an enumeration of the non-trivial partitioners of $\mathscr{A}'$, where $\kappa\le 2^\omega$. For $\eta<\kappa$ recursively choose distinct $C_\eta,D_\eta\in\mathscr{A}'\setminus\big(\{C_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\cup\{D_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\big)$ so that $C_\eta\subseteq^*X_\eta$ and $D_\eta\cap X_\eta=^*\varnothing$. To see that this is always possible, note that $\eta<2^\omega=|F_X|$, so we can certainly choose $C_\eta$; and ${}^{<\omega}2\setminus X$ is also a partitioner of $\mathscr{A}'$, so for essentially the same reason we can choose $D_\eta$.

Finally, let

$$\mathscr{M}=\{C_\xi\cup D_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}\cup\Big(\mathscr{A}'\setminus\big(\{C_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}\cup\{D_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}\big)\Big)\;;$$

then $\mathscr{M}$ is a MAD family with no non-trivial partitioners: the sets $C_\xi\cup D_\xi$ kill off every potential non-trivial partitioner.

Comment: I am just now getting to your post.  What is $\wp(T)$ ?

Comment: @Tom: The power set of $T$. (I’m in the habit of using $\wp$ for the power set, simply because it greatly resembles the handwritten form that I use in that context.)

Comment: I have one more question related to this. There is a theorem which says any compact metric space without isolated points (in particular, every metric continuum) is homeomorphic to the Stone-Cech remainder of $\Psi (\mathcal A)$ for some MAD family $\mathcal A$.  So the remainder of $\Psi (\mathcal A)$ can be an indecomposable continuum. I wonder what conditions on $\mathcal A$ will make the remainder indecomposable.  I do not think there has been any research in this area.  How might you approach this problem?

Comment: @Tom: To be honest, I wouldn’t: I’ve simply never had much interest in geometric topology, in which I include most continua theory, and have managed to avoid learning much about it.

Comment: Fair enough. thanks